# Expectation value of stochastic differential equation using Fokker-Planck distributions

Tags: statistics, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a stochastic variable $x(t)$ with known steady-state Fokker-Planck distribution $P(x)$, i.e. for any $f(x)$, its expectation value is

$$\overline{(f(x))}=\int dx f(x) P(x) $$

My question is what happens to $f(x)=\dot{x}(t)$? Is it correct to assume that

$$\int dx \dot{x}(t) P(x) = \overline{\dot{x}(t)}$$

I do know the form of $\dot{x}(t)=-a x(t)+b \eta(t)$, where $\overline{\eta(t)}=0$ and $\overline{\eta(t)\eta(t')}=\delta(t-t')$. What can I say about $\overline{\dot{x}}$?

Answer (score 1):

From a formal point of view, you take an average in a mathematics way, the average over a distribution as an expected value.

$E\{f(x)\} = \int \mathrm{d}x f(x)P(x)$

And the weird thing is that this expected value is given in a certain time $t$, the problem is that, from a physical point of view it does not make a sens since the process is realized one time and you cannot measure the expected value. However from a math point it is ok, and expected value is not measured over time, so you can perform a differentiation and put it inside of an expected value as you write. The issue that you will face, is that a $\dot{x}(t)$ might have a different statistics so you should integrate over a different probability density function if you want to know expected value.

Also do you mean $\delta (t)$ instead of $dt$? and $\nu(t)$ is a white noise?

From the bottom equation I see that $E\{\dot{x}(t)\} = aE\{x(t)\}$.

If you want to calculate an auto-correlation R of $\dot{x}(t)$, then it is $R_{\dot{x}\dot{x}}(t_1,t_2) E\{\dot{x}(t_1)\dot{x}(t_2)\} = \frac{d}{dt_1}\frac{d}{dt_2}E\{x(t_1)x(t_2)\}$ and it seems like it is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t_1 \partial t_1} R_{xx}(t_1,t_2)$. If the process is stationary, then the autocorrelation of derivative is

$R_{\dot{x}\dot{x}}(t_1,t_2) = R_{\dot{x}\dot{x}}(\tau) = - R^{''}_{xx}(\tau)$,

since derivative is a system with a transfer function $j\omega$, and if you calculate the spectral density of the system $|j\omega j\omega| \rightarrow -\frac{d^2}{d\tau^2}$

Comment: You are right about the dt, it was wrong. I edited it. So $\eta(t)$ is a white noise, and $x(t)$ is a colored noise. Physically speaking, I have a system driven by colored noise, but the coupling to it is via $\dot{x}(t)$, which makes it confusing. About your last line: Shouldn't I use Itô's rule? $E\{\dot{x^2}\}=E\{\dot{x}x\}+E\{x\dot{x}\}+E\{\dot{x}\dot{x}\}$

Comment: I was mistaken in the last line

Comment: I made some corrections. As for Itô's rule, I do not know. BTW, it is not clear for me what do you want to achieve.  is your equation is : $\dot{x}(t)=-a x(t)+b \eta(t)$? you can calculate the power spectral density of this equation from a transfer function, if it is what you are searching for. If you noise couples somehow to your system, why don't you just find a transfer function of that "master" equation and then calculate whatever quantities you need to know?

Comment: Is your solution is $\tilde{x} = x_0(t) + x(t)+ \nu(t)$ where $x_0(t)$ is non-stochastic solution, $x(t)$ is a colored noise?

Comment: Ok, I have found your equation, is this it? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/756689/how-to-take-the-average-of-a-stochastic-differential-equation